# print all the nodes which are multiples of root node using java

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Suppose this is the binary tree case. (See below image.)   I need to print all the nodes on in-order traversal and it must be printing multiple of root node only.

[image: binary tree]

For the binary tree, above, my desired output will be **20 10 25 5 15 30**

Here is my code

```
class Node {
    int data;
    Node left, right;

    Node(int value) {
        data = value;
        left = right = null;
    }
}

class Tree {
    Node root;

    Tree() {
        root = null;
    }

    // Method to construct a binary tree from the given array (Do not edit the code given below)
    public Node insertNode(int[] elementsArr, Node node, int i) {
        if (i < elementsArr.length) {
            node = new Node(elementsArr[i]);
            node.left = insertNode(elementsArr, node.left, 2 * i + 1);
            node.right = insertNode(elementsArr, node.right, 2 * i + 2);
        }
        return node;
    }

    // Method to print nodes that are multiple of root node
    //NOte -  i have updated the printNode method but still not getting desired output
    public void printNodes(Node node) {
        // Write your code here
        if (node == null)
            return;
        if(node.data% root.data==0) {
            printNodes(node.left);
            System.out.print(node.data+ " ");
            printNodes(node.right);
        }
    }
}

/*Don't change main class also*/
public class PrintSpecificNodes {
    public static void main(String[] x) {
        Tree tree = new Tree();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int size;
        size = sc.nextInt();

        if (size <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Size should be a positive integer");
        } else {
            int[] elementsArr = new int[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                elementsArr[i] = sc.nextInt();
            }
            tree.root = tree.insertNode(elementsArr, tree.root, 0);
            tree.printNodes(tree.root);
        }
    }
}
```

What changes do I have to make in method `printNodes()` to get my desired output?

Comment: What result are you getting with this code ?

Comment: only true five times but im not able to get how to filter the output so that it can only display the multiple of root node.Just check the ***printNode(Node node) {}*** method what to change

Comment: the method seems to be ok, what do you mean by "only true five times"

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46918053/binary-search-tree-filter-values-in-a-range

Comment: Did you try changing `node.data % node.data` to `node.data % root.data` ?

Comment: @Quade its printing true true true true true

Comment: @Abra yes i have tried in this way **`public void printNodes(Node node) {
        // Write your code here
        if (node == null)
            return;
        if(node.data% root.data==0) {
            printNodes(node.left);
            System.out.print(node.data+ " ");
            printNodes(node.right);
        }
    }`**
suppose my input is 
5
3 4 5 6 7 
my output should be 3 6 
but now i get only 3

Answer (score 1):

public void printNodes(Node node){

```
    if (node == null)
        return;
    if(node.data==0){
        System.out.println("Division by zero is undefined");
        return;
    }
    printNodes(node.left);

    if(node.data % root.data == 0){
        System.out.print(node.data + " ");
    }
    printNodes(node.right);
}
```

this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print(node.data % node.data + " ");
```

will get 0

method printNodes should know the value of root

```
    public void printNodes(Node node) {
        if (node == null) return;
        printNodes(node.left);
        if(node.data % root.data == 0){
            System.out.println(node.data);
        }
        printNodes(node.right);
    }
```

Comment: Since method `printNodes()` is in class `Tree`, doesn't it have access to the `root` member of that class? If it does, then why does it need to be a parameter of the method?

Comment: Right.Didn't notice class tree.Suppose to only node class.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void printNodes(Node node){
    // Write your code here
    if(node == null)
    return ;
        if(node.data==0){
        System.out.println("Division by zero is not defined");
        return;
        }
    printNodes(node.left);
    if(node.data%root.data==0)
    {
        System.out.print(node.data+ " ");
    }
    printNodes(node.right);

}
```

I think this should solve your problem, since it is an Inorder transversal it should be left-Root-right and it should also check for whether some number is 0 or not. If it's a 0 then it won't print anything (division by 0 is not defined).